# I saw a Straight 30 lights line above night sky this evening, around 7:30pm,march 16,2024  that flying light objects goes to the moon then gone

Tags: artificial-satellite

I saw a Straight 30 lights line above night sky this evening, around 7:30pm,march 16,2024 at the country of Oman, location Al Qurum beach  . that flying  light objects goes to the moon then gone,I'm not tue only one that i saw that straight lines line object, we're three of us and got a video of it.

Comment: This was a StarLink train of satellites. They were all launched together and stay close together for their first few orbits before slowly separating.